# Optaplanner Vehicle routing Update

Tags: optaplanner

I'm trying to update the version of Optaplanner Vehicle routing here at the company I work for and I'm having difficulties. I noticed that the latest version installed here is the:
Implementation-Version: 7.6.0.Final

And we used two important services that are no longer available:
RouteAPI ===> https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/routeapi
menorkm ===> https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/menorkm

Is it possible to find the .war of these services updated today? Where?

Finally, I want to use the system in the similar to what you see in this link:
http://xxx.xx.x.xxx/routeapi/vehiclerouting/leaflet.jsp

How do i proceed?

Comment: Neither of those two github URL's ever existed. That must be code from your company specifically, not part of optaplanner upstream.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [optaweb-vehicle-routing](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaweb-vehicle-routing) and [the upgrade recipe to upgrade to 8](https://www.optaplanner.org/download/upgradeRecipe/).